# PHP: HTML inside if statement inside while loop

Tags: php, html, if-statement, while-loop

I've used HTML inside loops and if statements before without problems. But now I got stuck.

I have a while loop and an if statement in it like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $gcode = $row ['code'];
    $gname = $row ['gname'];
    $firstletter = substr($gname, 0, 1);
    if ($gid == $firstletter) {?><div>some html</div><?php}
}
```

It just won't work. No warning message or anything, just a blank page. However, if I substitute the HTML with echo like this, it works.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $gcode = $row ['code'];
    $gname = $row ['gname'];
    $firstletter = substr($gname, 0, 1);
    if ($gid == $firstletter) {echo "some html";}
}
```

Could anyone please advise. Thank you!

Comment: where is `$gid` defined?

Comment: The error is in `some html` I suppose. But as you don show it - no one can help.

Comment: If this is not whole code, and other answers does not help. Try echoing '<div>lalal</div> maybe your elements are hidden on the page or something'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Just need to add some space `if ($gid == $firstletter) { ?><div>some html</div><?php }` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

When I put your code in my editor I had an error.  It does not like the fact there no space in between the php and the }.

Try it like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $gcode = $row ['code'];
    $gname = $row ['gname'];
    $firstletter = substr($gname, 0, 1);
    if ($gid == $firstletter) {?><div>some html</div><?php } //<--Just add a space.

}
```